# How to find the center of rows in a grayscale image of a data table

Tags: image-processing

I have such images

[image]

I want to draw a red line in every line content like this:
[image]

If I accumulate the pixel value for every line, I can get the red curve line:

```
black = ImageRotate[ColorNegate[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/skpSZ.png"]]];
data = Plus @@ ImageData[black];
Show[black, ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

I think the position of the yellow arrow is what I want to find... But how to find it? **Of course, I know the number of the line must be 10 in every column. Because the digits are always from 0 to 9.**
And I have another such images to do such thing..

image2

[image]

image3

[image]

image4

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not as succinct as I'd hoped, but here it is:

```
highlight[img_] := Module[
  {binary, pixelsPerRow, clusters, diffs, occupied, empty, intervals, 
   means, imgw, imgh},
  padded = ImagePad[img, 1];
  binary = Binarize[ColorNegate[padded]];
  pixelsPerRow = Total[ImageData[binary], {2}];
  clusters = FindClusters[
    pixelsPerRow -> Range@Length[pixelsPerRow], 5,
    Method -> "KMeans"
    ];
  diffs = Differences[First[clusters]];
  occupied = DeleteCases[diffs, 1];
  empty = SequenceCases[diffs, {seq : 1 ..} :> Length[{seq}]];
  intervals = Partition[Accumulate@Riffle[empty, occupied], 2];
  means = Pick[Mean /@ intervals, EuclideanDistance[##] > 15 & @@@ intervals];
  {imgw, imgh} = ImageDimensions[img];
  HighlightImage[img, InfiniteLine[{0, imgh - # + 1}, {1, 0}] & /@ means]
  ]
```

The basic idea is that rows where there is no text always have the same, or almost the same, number of white pixels. They also have fewer pixels than any other rows. This means that if we cluster the pixel counts per row then the first cluster will consist of the empty rows. We can then use those row numbers to figure out where to put the red lines.

There is a magic number, 15, in this algorithm. Without any correction, this algorithm would have drawn red lines through horizontal white lines because they aren't empty. What the number 15 denotes is that if non-empty sequences of rows are shorter than fifteen rows then they shouldn't be highlighted with red lines.

Examples:

```
img1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJbkm.png"];
img2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hetHU.png"];
img3 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CU49.png"];

GraphicsColumn[highlight /@ {img1, img2, img3}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: How about [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9N3ov.png)?

Comment: @yode Doesn't it work, or what?

Comment: Yes, I will get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK5AI.png)

Comment: @yode ok, I see. It was easily fixed by padding the image. I've updated the function.

Comment: Then `img2` will have [an extra red line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbXnY.png)...

Comment: @yode Because the last line is broader than 10 pixels. I increased the threshold to 15.

Comment: Why should we find 5 cluster by `FindClusters`, not 6 or more less?

Comment: And it is seem [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in6eJ.png) is a good condtion. but you have no use it to find cluster?

Comment: @yode The number of clusters is arbitrary, really. I think that at least for some images there is such a thing as too few clusters. For example, if you have two clusters and some outliers then it may put the outliers in one cluster and everything else in the other. So you have to have enough clusters to deal with that. Apart from that, the first cluster is quite well separated which you can see by plotting `pixelsPerRow`, as I did. As for using the number of lines in total, it may be that that can be used to improve the algorithm. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to explore this.

Answer (score 1):

Just a start to try,

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoCAX.png"]
```

[image]

```
whiteCount = Total /@ ImageData[Binarize@img];
median = Median[whiteCount];
tmp = SplitBy[whiteCount, Sign[# - median] &];
pos = Pick[Accumulate[Length /@ tmp] - 1/2 Length /@ tmp, 
   Length[#] > 5 && #[[1]] < median & /@ tmp];
dims = ImageDimensions[img];
HighlightImage[img, 
 Line[{{1, dims[[2]] - #}, {dims[[1]], dims[[2]] - #}} & /@ pos]]
```

[image]

But this code cannot success to use in other images.. Because I have use the median as a threshold here...