# How to find the rectangle with those text

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing

In this image:

[image]

I want to find this rectangle with all contents(without those grid's lines)

[image]

I think the total of the pixels can help a little like:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnd5w.png"];
data = Total[ImageData[ImageRotate[ColorNegate[img]]]];
Show[ImageRotate[img], 
 ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

And I have such images:

image2

[image]

image3

[image]

image4

[image]

image5

[image]

I have no idea to do this thing. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you asked this question before? It seems very familiar to me...

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186174/how-to-find-the-mark-centroid) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183780/how-to-find-the-center-of-rows-in-a-grayscale-image-of-a-data-table). Just for context purposes :)

Comment: @CarlLange It's not very similar...

Comment: The question isn't but the images are, so I wanted to make sure it wasn't a duplicate somehow. That's all!

Answer (score 5):

Binarization and `ComponentMeasurements` seems the straightforward solution:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnd5w.png"];
```

Selct all components that are less than half as long as the image:

```
comp = ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalBinarize[ColorNegate@img], 
   "BoundingBox", #CaliperLength < Min[ImageDimensions[img]]*0.5 &];
```

This selects all digits and boxes, but not the grid lines, because they are longer than height/2:

```
HighlightImage[img, Rectangle @@@ comp[[All, 2]]]
```

[image]

Then combine the individual bounding boxes to one big bounding box:

```
HighlightImage[img, 
 Rectangle @@ 
  Transpose[MinMax /@ Transpose[Flatten[comp[[All, 2]], 1]]]]
```

[image]

You might have to adjust binarization and the criteria in `ComponentMeasurements`, but for me, it worked on all the images you posted on the first try.

Comment: Sorry for catching a cold to delay response. Your method is very simple to understand. But your method cannot deal with the [image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9flG.png). This is why I want to do it with signal-processing method...

Comment: @yode: Sure it can, you just need to adjust the criteria function in `ComponentMeasurements`.

Answer (score 3):

This works quite well:

```
findRegion[img_] := TextRecognize[img, "BoundingBox", RecognitionPrior -> "SparseText"]

HighlightImage[#, findRegion@#] & /@ imgs
```

[image]

As you can see, the result for the first image is not perfect unfortunately, but hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Yes, as your try, the Tesseract not very stable..